# Pointers in C++. What type of object

Tags: c++, c, pointers, typedef

I saw this code in the book and thought a lot about this.

```
typedef string *qstring;
const qstring cstr
```

What type of `cstr` ? Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `qstring` is a typedef of `string *` - a pointer to `string`. The `const` in `const qstring` applies to the outermost type of `qstring`, so it applies to the pointer, which makes `cstr` have type `string * const`.

Answer (score 2):

Typedefs are not simple text substitution, so modifiers will never affect the insides.

`cstr` is a pointer to a `string`, and it is `const`.  It is not a pointer to a `const string`.

Answer (score 2):

Qualifiers (`const` is a qualifier) never penetrate a `typedef`.

So `const qstring` type is `string * const` and not `const string *`.

Answer (score 1):

**cstr** has type

```
string * const
```

not

```
const string *
```